# Android - The text view text is returning null but the condition doesn't match

Tags: java, android

I'm following a Android Studio tutorial and this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResponse);
        TextView tvError = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvError);

        tvResult.setText(result);

        mLoadingProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Log.d("Error", result);
        if(result == null) {
            tvResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tvError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("Error", "null");
        }
        else {
            tvResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d("Error", "not null");
        }
    }
```

For some reason lands the else, even though the result is null.

I ran it in debugging mode and the log it shows is:

```
D/Error: null
    not null
```

Comment: if(result.equals("")) use this

Comment: probably because result is not null. It has a string "null" in it. try `"null".equalsignorecase(result) || result == null`

Comment: Check if the value in your `result` string is "nul"

Comment: @MayurPanchal - doing that will throw a NPE when result is null

Comment: Debug this .. Can it be the case the result contains `"null"` . Use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` for string ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (result != null && !result.isEmpty())
{
        tvResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.d("Error", "not null");
 }
 else{
        tvResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d("Error", "null");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one method to string null or not

```
public boolean isEmptyString(String inputStr) {
        if (inputStr != null && !inputStr.equals("") && inputStr.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

Use this method like this

```
if(isEmptyString(result))
{
///Null
else
{
/// Not null
}
```